# How to use Git LFS+ with nodegit?

Tags: git, git-lfs, libgit2, gitkraken

I use [nodegit](https://github.com/nodegit/nodegit) for my NodeJS project and would like to use Git LFS support (`nodegit` uses [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/) under the hood). I found [nodegit-lfs](https://github.com/Axosoft/nodegit-lfs) - also from Axosoft - whose description states:

> Nodegit LFS is an extension library used to augment NodeGit with the capability to use git lfs via the command line.
> To use this package, you must have git and git lfs installed.

So it seems the standard Git installation is required for this "add-on" but due to license restrictions I can't use that (The reference Git implementation has a slightly different license as nodegit/libgit2 **and** Git LFS)

Does anyone know how if there is another way to use Git LFS with nodegit?

P.S. I attempted to add the hooks for Git LFS to my test repo but it seems libgit2 doesn't execute them, so no success on this.

Comment: Git LFS requires Git to work, so while you can implement the LFS protocol yourself based on the docs in the repository, if you want to call out to Git LFS manually, you'll need Git as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with nodegit : if a repo contains hooks and filters and attributes, executing regular git commands (such as `add`, `commit` ...) through nodegit will not trigger these hooks ?